# How do I open the software and updates panel from the command line?

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am trying to write a bash script that secures various Ubuntu versions (16.04, 18.04, and maybe 20.04) with as little user effort as possible. I have seen that you can open the GNOME settings panel from the terminal, and was wondering if the same was true for the Software and Updates panel.

Answer (score 0):

Found it!
I used `strace -e execve -f update-manager` to find what was run when opening the settings from inside of the update manager window. Hopefully someone who needs this finds it.

Comment: Simply `update-manager` will do.

Answer (score 0):

On Lubuntu 20.04, to open the graphical Update Notifier from the command line, you can run

```
$ /usr/lib/lubuntu-update-notifier/lubuntu-upg-notifier.sh
```

Note, this script checks for upgrades every hour until it's terminated.